# Revtex: rmp with phys rev style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex

By rmp option to revtex4-1 sets the citation style to author/year. I'd like to change it to standard numerical citation, as seen in Physical Review Journals, (but with reference section name as in rmp instead of the horizontal line). The author guide says the following:

> The [bibliography style] selection can be overridden by specifying an alternative .bst file using the standard LaTeX2e \bibliographystyle macro. This must appear in the preamble before the \begin{document} line in REVTeX 4.1 (this differs from standard LaTeX).

However, doing that has no effect. Instead, I have figured out that I can change natbib options, however it doesn't work exactly as expected. It doesn't compress citation numbers and citation grouping (star syntax) doesn't work. I suspect it's because under the covers revtex still uses author/year citations, and natbib options only change the appearance. Is there a way to actually force rmp to use proper numbered citations?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add some code to play with?

Comment: See this post for your answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264470/force-numeric-citations-in-revtex