# Force numeric citations in RevTex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, revtex

I am using the Review of Modern Physics (`rmp`) style for a report. By default, it uses author/year citations. I want to force revtex to use numerical citations.

Adding the `\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}` as described in the documentation (or including `numerical` in the `documentclass` statement) doesn't seem to help.

Here is an example tex file that suffers from this problem.

```
\documentclass[rmp]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
\begin{document}
More words Citation: \cite{cite2}

Other citation:\cite{cite1} 

%include bibliography
\bibliography{bibstuff}

\end{document}
```

with bibstuff.bib:

```
@article{cite1,
    Author = {John Doe and James Doe},
    Issue = {71},
    Journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    Month = {Mar},
    Numpages = {0},
    Pages = {5321},
    Publisher = {American Physical Society},
    Title = {SCIENCE!},
    Volume = {32},
    Year = {1994}}

@article{cite2,
Author = {Jane Name and Other Person},
    Issue = {71},
    Journal = {Phys. Rev. E},
    Month = {Mar},
    Numpages = {0},
    Pages = {5321},
    Publisher = {American Physical Society},
    Title = {SCIENCE!},
    Volume = {32},
    Year = {2078}}
}
```

Link to the documentation:
http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/370/papers/Journal_Style_Manuals/auguide4-1.pdf

Comment: Changing to `\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}` (the style for journals of the American Institute of Physics) gives numerical style, but I don't know if it also introduces some other undesired formatting changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the suitable `\setcitestyle` command:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite1,
    Author = {John Doe and James Doe},
    Issue = {71},
    Journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    Month = {Mar},
    Numpages = {0},
    Pages = {5321},
    Publisher = {American Physical Society},
    Title = {SCIENCE!},
    Volume = {32},
    Year = {1994}}

@article{cite2,
Author = {Jane Name and Other Person},
    Issue = {71},
    Journal = {Phys. Rev. E},
    Month = {Mar},
    Numpages = {0},
    Pages = {5321},
    Publisher = {American Physical Society},
    Title = {SCIENCE!},
    Volume = {32},
    Year = {2078}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[rmp]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}

\setcitestyle{numbers,square}

\begin{document}

More words Citation: \cite{cite2}

Other citation: \cite{cite1} 

%include bibliography
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents` only for making the example self-contained; any `bib` file will do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. 
Could you link to somewhere that this feature (`\setcitestyle{}`) is documented?

Comment: @taciteloquence It's documented in the manual of `natbib`, the package `revtex` uses for bibliography and citation management.

Comment: With revtex4-1 and revtex4-2, this loses natbib's "sort&compress" option, where multiple citations are formatted as e.g. `[1-3]` instead of `[1; 2; 3]`. Is there any way to restore it?

Comment: @MichaelGoerz `\setcitestyle{numbers,square,sort&compress}`

Comment: @egreg I tried that, but it does not seem to have any effect. Does that work for you?